# How to filtering MySQL table using another query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

UserTable

```
id  nama
--  -------------------
1   Administrator
11  Agung
21  Sagita
50  John
100 Purnama
```

Filtertable

```
id  idlist
--  ------------------
1   1,21,100
2   21,50
```

So I want to query name table with id from the second table

```
SELECT id, nama FROM UserTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT idlist FROM FilterTable WHERE id =1)
```

But In MySQL the result only show

```
    id  nama           
------  ---------------
     1  Administrator
```

While it should show at least 3 rows from UserTable

I think this should be easy but I've tried search google and stackoverflow without solution, kindly show me how to get what I need

This is a simplification, further implementation is for saving search history (the table's ids) from visitors

Comment: Normalize the schema. See: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get the results you expect if you use a string (the result of your `(SELECT idlist FROM FilterTable WHERE id =1)` subquery) as an input to an `IN` expression; MySQL will attempt to convert it to an integer to match the value (`id`) being tested, resulting in `1,21,100` being converted to `1` and matching only the `Administrator` value. Instead, you should use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to compare:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nama
FROM UserTable u
JOIN FilterTable f ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, f.idlist)
WHERE f.id = 1
```

Or (using a subquery)

```
SELECT id, nama
FROM UserTable u
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (SELECT idlist FROM FilterTable WHERE id =1))
```

Output:

```
id      nama
1       Administrator
21      Sagita
100     Purnama
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pTTBt7Tm8oCxcTMxZyRPFD/1)

Your life would be much easier if your schema was properly normalised. Please read: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)